# PSConfig inplace upgrade - Failed to start service SearchServiceInstance

Tags: 2013, search, psconfig

I had some free time on my hands lately, so I decided to fix some of issues in Health Analyzer. I decided on fixing database need to be upgraded error.

I ran following command:

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

Which successfully finished first four configuration steps. However, when It got to "Upgrading SharePointProducts" script had displayed following error:

```
10.00% : Failed to start service SearchServiceInstance on this server after completing upgrade. Please start it manually.
```

Short googling after, I ran following command, which finished succesfully

```
stsadm -o osearch -action start
```

And now I wonder - do I need to restart PSconfig, should I wait for it to continue, or something else?

PS. If it wasn't clear from answer below - yes, you need to restart. It will not continue by itself.

Comment: please mention your SharePoint version

Comment: are you tried to run Config wizard for all SharePoint servers , also check the status of servers in farm if it required upgrade or not ?

Comment: There is only one server - it is dev machine, all in one box.

Comment: ok from services try to start Search Service manually as it's said , or restart your machine

Comment: So, the command will not return if it failed at any point?

Comment: after you make sure that the service is up to running, run the config wizard again or psconfig.exe command that should be worked without any issue but it will start from step 1 not continue, please tell me if it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an error message in PSConfig because of a service is offline, you need to start PSConfig again and make sure you have a successful run. Also verify that you have the target build version in Manage servers in this farm (http://CA-url:port/_admin/FarmServers.aspx) and Check product and patch installation status (http://CA-url:port/_admin/PatchStatus.aspx).

You need to have a successful run, and all runs can be found in Check upgrade status (http://CA-url:port/_admin/UpgradeStatus.aspx)